# ViewModel Binding issue

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a viewModel in my view page which is binded as below:

```
var form = $("form");

    $(function () {
        var viewModel = kendo.observable(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'));

        kendo.bind(form, viewModel[0]);
    });
```

But the problem here is i am using viewModel[0]  which looks odd to me.

Can we rewrite the binding code to like below without [0], this will give issues while binding

```
  kendo.bind(form, viewModel);
```

This is my view:

```
@model IList<PC.CManager.Cs.Domain.Models.Ln>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading inform" style="">
            <table clases="panel-title inform">
                <tr>
                    <td class="inform">Loan Number: <label id="loannum" name="loannum">1000100001</label></td>
                    <td class="inform">Status: <label id="loanstatus" name="loanstatus">Forclosure</label></td>
                    <td class="inform">Loan Type: <label id="loantype" name="loantype">Government(FHA)</label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Controller :

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> ClaimDetail()
        {
            //return View();
            string id = "1000000246";
             if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var LnDetail = await _LnProxy.GetLnDetailByLnNum((string)id);
            if (LnDetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(LnDetail);
        }
```

How we can rewrite the binding code to looks good and work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use only the first element, and that is how it should be because you are getting it by "id", you can return only single element instead of List of elements.

```
var LnDetail = await _LnProxy.GetLnDetailByLnNum((string)id).FirstOrDefault();
```

And then your model will be:

```
@model PC.CManager.Cs.Domain.Models.Ln
```

Then in JavaScript you can use it without the angle brackets, just viewModel. Because it will be a single object now, not an array.